# Update column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

All,

I tried to update column C_NEW in my table with data within the table but stuck not sure where to start. I hope bottom explaination help.

```
C1      | C2      | C3      | C4         | C_NEW
-------- --------- --------- ------------ -------
1@a.com | e@a.com | e@a.com | 1@a.com    |
1@a.com | e@a.com | 4@b.com | 12@f.com   |
1@a.com | e@a.com | 5@b.com | 123@k.com  |
4@b.com | b@a.com | 4@b.com | ab@123.com |
4@b.com | b@a.com | d@a.com | abc@12.com |
2@c.com | 3@c.com | b@1.com | a12@ff.com |
```

Email need to sent to user in C1 in combination of C1 and C2, so three separate email should sent to 1@a.com, 4@b.com and 2@c.com

Copy to user in C3 that is not in C1 or C2, so in the column C_NEW I want to have (4@b.com; 5@b.com) to fill in first three rows and (d@a.com) should fill in row four and five and (b@1.com) should fill in the last row in C_NEW column.

also need to copy user in column C4 that is not in C1.  So the update column C_NEW should have (4@b.com; 5@b.com; 12@f.com; 123@k.com) to fill in first three rows and (d@a.com; ab@123.com; abc@12.com) should fill in row four and five and (b@1.com; a12@ff.com) should fill in the last row in C_New column.

With the above data I should have three reports...

```
Report A: 1@a.com
Email to:
Copy to: 4@b.com; 5@b.com; 12@f.com; 123@k.com


Report B:
Email to: 4@b.com
Copy to: d@a.com; ab@123.com; abc@12.com

Report C:
Email to: 2@c.com
Copy to: b@1.com; a12@ff.com
```

The table final result shoul look like this

```
C1      | C2      | C3      | C4         | C_NEW
-------- --------- --------- ------------ -------
1@a.com | e@a.com | e@a.com | 1@a.com    | 4@b.com; 5@b.com; 12@f.com; 123@k.com
1@a.com | e@a.com | 4@b.com | 12@f.com   | 4@b.com; 5@b.com; 12@f.com; 123@k.com
1@a.com | e@a.com | 5@b.com | 123@k.com  | 4@b.com; 5@b.com; 12@f.com; 123@k.com
4@b.com | b@a.com | 4@b.com | ab@123.com | d@a.com; ab@123.com; abc@12.com
4@b.com | b@a.com | d@a.com | abc@12.com | d@a.com; ab@123.com; abc@12.com
2@c.com | 3@c.com | b@1.com | a12@ff.com | b@1.com; a12@ff.com
```

Comment: Really sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking for. Anyway you can make this clearer? For example here "Copy to user in C3 that is not in C1 or C2, so in the column C_NEW I want to have (4@b.com; 5@b.com)" I'm confused as 4@b.com IS in C1.

Comment: I'm also a little confused.  Can you show us what C_NEW should look like after the update?  Once C_NEW has been updated will that answer your question?

Comment: @destination-data I just added the table final result should look like and yes once C_NEW updated that answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Update your existing Data through select statement.

In this you select all C3 and C4 with your conditions ans do an `UNION`. This list you have to concat through `XML PATH` and build your `C_NEW` column.

```
UPDATE [Table]
    SET C_NEW = SelectTable.C_NEW
FROM
( 
    SELECT [Table].c1, [Table].c2, c3, c4, SUBSTRING(t2.C_NEW , 2, LEN(t2.C_NEW)) AS C_NEW
    FROM dbo.[Table]
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT C1, C2, (
        (SELECT ', ' + C3 AS [text()]  FROM (
            SELECT C1, c2, C3 FROM [Table]
            WHERE C3 <> C1 AND C3 <> C2 AND C1 = t.C1 AND C2 = t.C2
            UNION 
            SELECT C1, c2, C4 FROM [Table]
            WHERE C4 <> C1 AND C1 = t.C1 AND C2 = t.C2
        ) AS t3 For XML PATH (''))
    )
    AS C_NEW
    FROM [Table] AS t
    GROUP BY C1, C2, t.C_NEW
    ) AS t2 ON t2.C1 = [Table].C1 AND t2.C2 = [Table].C2
) AS SelectTable
WHERE [Table].C1 = SelectTable.C1 
    AND [Table].C2 = SelectTable.C2 
    AND [Table].C3 = SelectTable.C3
    AND [Table].C4 = SelectTable.C4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @take, took me a while to apply your code to my issue.  Have a nice day.

Comment: there is a white space on the left (front) of each record in the C_NEW column after I applied your above code.  I tried to twist your code but no luck.  I'm using LTRIM for a quick fix.  If you figure it out, please let me know.  Thank you

Comment: is it possible to do this in a loop instead XML PATH? I started `UPDATE [Table]
    SET C_NEW = CASE 
                  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                               FROM   [Table] T
                               WHERE  T.C1 <> T.C3) THEN dbo.[Table].C3 + '; '         
                  ELSE ''
                END`